# Bring MdiChild To Front (Using WPF.MDI)

Tags: c#, wpf, mdichild

I'm trying to make MdiForm on WPF application. But I'm getting stuck on how to bring to front selected form. In VB6 I usually used

```
FrmName.ZOrder
```

Is there any similarity I can use on WPF?

Anyway this is my code:

```
using WPF.MDI;
foreach (MdiChild c in mdiMain.Children)
{
    if (c.Title == "Setup Customer")
    {
        c.BringToFront();    //I'm having trouble here
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach (MdiChild c in mdiMain.Children)
{
    if (c.Title == "Setup Customer")
    {
        c.Focus();    //TRY THIS
        return;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to mark this as answer too if it fits your needs